# Having some problems with Object Oriented Java, is this right?

Tags: java, oop

Im bulding a game and i decided to organize it using a GameState abstract class, so i could define menus, levels and stuff.

I have a class called GameStateManager that holds all states and change them when needed.
Is it right to pass in the GameState contructor an instance of the GameStateManager just to acess his methods for state changing?

If not is there other way?

Comment: What is the difference between a GameState and a GameStateManager? I'm missing that.

Comment: That doesn't sound unreasonable to me, possibly some usage examples would make this clearer thought. Also; just to warn you, this may be off topic for stack overflow, might be on topic on programmers if you made it a generic enough question

Comment: GameStateManager holds all the GameStates, and sets the current one that is running.

Comment: @Thomas possibly equivalent to the relationship between a physics engine and a physics object. One manages and one *is* and they (in some implementations) both have references to each other

Comment: So could i pass an instance just because they are related?

Comment: Usually I pass an instance whenever an object needs access to annother. Its generally a good idea **not** to pass 'this' in a contructor though so you want it so you manager.addState (state) and then that method 'wires up' the reciprocal references rather than trying to do it in a constructor

Comment: Given your definition of GameStateManager, I'd say no, don't pass it in. GameStageManger might have a factory method for creating GameStates, however.

Comment: What you try to do is something like a `Mediator`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right to pass in the GameState contructor an instance of the GameStateManager just to acess his methods for state changing?

No.

You should only ever have one instance and one reference of the manager. That means you should use an instance-based system. For example:

```
GameStateManager instance = GameStateManager.getInstance();
```

That way you can access it statically.

This can be done in such a manner:

```
// in GameStateManager.java

private static GameStateManager instance;

protected static GameStateManager getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new GameStateManager(); //private constructor
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I assume `protected` will work here, on the basis that all GameState instances are in the same package as the GameStateManager.

Comment: Well I have thought about sigleton pattern, but imagine that I want 2 games running in the same computer and same JVM, I dont want them to have the same state everytime.

Comment: @PatriqDesigns that won't happen.

Comment: There is nothing that requires a singleton about the GameStateManager, and it is bad form to make it a singleton unless you are absolutely sure it should be one.

Comment: Even though that scenario is very very unlikely, considering I cannot find a situation in which it would happen and be proper, you can then manage them on a threadgroup basis, to every threadgroup has their own GameStateManager.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes there is. You don't want to have 2-3 running at once interfering.

Comment: How do you know whether a GameStateManager can't have multiple instances? There is not even remotely enough information in this question to know this. Most singleton patterns like this are just gross ways to hide global variables.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this question comes **exactly** from a game-making tutorial. I could even provide the link to it, it was posted on reddit a while ago. I know exactly how it is used and under what circumstances it is defined under. This way of managing GameStates is ideal.

Comment: "Running"? The managers aren't threads, and they can be made to not "interfere." The singleton pattern is *way* overused.

Comment: Well thats a possibity to have one more than one GameStateManager instance.
So how would i do things?
Want me to write everything, source?

Comment: @PatriqDesigns it is possible, but that is not recommended. I've done a lot of work in this field and know that with these cases, singletons are always better. You shouldn't ever use one GameStateManager for any reason.

Comment: Ok then I will try using singleton! :D

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to pass a `GameState` contructor *an instance* of a `GameStateManager` if that `GameState` can have a collection of `GameStates`, since you would need a `GameStateManager` to *manage* the `GameStates` for that `GameState`.

However, if that is not the case, I do **not** think that it makes sense to do pass the `GameStateManager` to the `GameState` constructor.  The whole point of the `GameStateManager` is to change the states, so, barring the above situation, a `GameState` should not be used to change the others *states*, the `GameStateManager` should be used.

If you're trying to figure out how to notify the `GameStateManager` that the current `GameState` needs to be changed, you could just have a `static` method in `GameStateManager` that you can call from `GameState` to change the current `GameState`.  If you don't want to make it `public`, which makes sense, so long as your classes are in the same package, you can make it `protected static`.  That should suit your purposes.

Comment: Yes! I know, so how can I change state, imagine for the PlayingState, if in the MenuState i hit the start option?

Comment: @PatriqDesigns I added a paragraph at the bottom.  Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: It seems to me that what you really might want is the GameStateManager to be a factory for GameStates, but that depends on whether there are too many distinct classes implementing GameState or not.

Comment: Well i was trying not to use static methods

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in OO, you need to ask yourself if `GameState` has a hard dependency (**composition**) on `GameStateManager` i.e. it can not perform without `GameStateManager`, then you can use the constructor to pass on `GameStateManager`.

If `GameState` has a soft dependency (**aggregation**) on `GameStateManager` i.e. it can perform without `GameStateManager`, then you can use the getter/setter to pass on `GameStateManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution would be to use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern): The `GameStateManager` knows all the `GameStates` (he is the *Observer* and must implement the `notify()`-method where he can handle the logic for game-state changes).

Upon creation of a new `GameState`, the `GameStateManager` has to register itself as observer like this: `newGameState.registerObserver(this)`.

When a `GameState` (the *subject*) changes, it calls notify for all listeners (e.g. only the single GameStateManager). This way, the GameState doesn't need to know the GameStateManager at all, but only knows that if it changes, some observers what to be notified.